# Specific element in a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given a set $A=\{a,b,c,d\}$ how can I take, for an example, the first element?
Like this: 
$A(0)=a; 
A(1)=b; 
A(0).A(1)=a.b$. 
I think there's no way to do that with sets, because it isn't an ordered set.

Comment: You may choose to order this set in 24 different ways.

Comment: Is $\lbrace a,b,c,d \rbrace \neq \lbrace c,d,b,a \rbrace$?

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft I think it is not. Only ordered sets are equals: (1,2) = (1,2) ≠ (2,1). However, {1,2} = {2,1}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a set $A$, there is no way to refer to its first element, second elements, or any such enumeration of elements, simply because a set is not ordered. You can ask whether an element is in a given set, and the answer is either yes or no. You can't ask where an element is placed in a given set, since no ordering exists in a set.

It is possible to consider some extra structure on a set, turning it into a poset (short for partially ordered set). Then you might be able to speak of first element, second element, and so on, but that is also not guaranteed. Posets that most closely resemble an ordering like you are alluding to are called well-orders. A finite well-order really looks just like a sequence of elements in order. But infinite well-orders can be very complicated.